# function() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given_def function in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, curve-fitting, exponential

I am trying to fit exponential function from my data. I am not very experienced with fitting mathematical functions to my data yet. 
Below is my code right now.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

my_x = (4,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40)
my_y = (0.022172333,0.020881,0.017729,0.021641333,0.02479,0.030755667,0.037235,0.048389,0.068451,0.06898974,0.161409,0.242802333,0.316012667,0.440762333,0.569118333,0.7016839,0.832527333)

def myfunc(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.exp(b*x)+c


p=[my_x,0.0045,0.1262,0] #pre-determined a=0.0045, b=0.1262, c=0 according to excel
popt, pcov = curve_fit(myfunc,my_x,my_y, p0=p)


plt.plot (my_x,myfunc(my_x, *popt))
```

The error message that I get is the following.

```
return function(xdata, *params) - ydata

TypeError: myfunc() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

I don't think I am quite understanding what this error message is saying. Could anyone help me understand what is causing this error and how I could improve my code?

Comment: It's saying that `params` contains four things, so with `xdata` you're passing five things to `myfunc`, which only takes four.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I see. but I am still having a hard time understanding what part of the current code indicates that it is giving five things to myfunc.

Comment: `myfunc(my_x, *popt)` spreads the elements of `popt` into separate arguments. So the problem is that `popt` is a list of 4 things, but it should be only 3.

Comment: check `p` ... it has a length of 4 ... I am expecting `popt` will thus have a length of 4 ... and hence unpacking that in the args will lead to 4 + 1 = 5 arguments ... are you sure `p` should have `my_x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `myfunc` function receive four parameters, `x`, `a`, `b` and `c`.

The error message says that you provided 5 parameters. It's because you unpacked `popt` who probably contains fours elements (and thus four paramaters while unpacking it).

In this line:

```
plt.plot (my_x,myfunc(my_x, *popt))
```

The `myfunc` function receive `my_x` + four parameters.
It makes five parameters but the function only wants four.

More about unpacking [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).